# error C2660: 'std::allocator<char>::allocate': function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2019, c++20

Code:

```
#include <string>

#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::format fmt;
    auto str = fmt % L"";
}
```

Errors:

> 1>D:.conan\a9fe50\1\include\boost\format\alt_sstream_impl.hpp(261,1):
> error C2660: 'std::allocator::allocate': function does not take
> 2 arguments 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xmemory(838,65):
> message : see declaration of 'std::allocator::allocate'
> 1>D:.conan\a9fe50\1\include\boost\format\alt_sstream_impl.hpp(228):
> message : while compiling class template member function 'int
> boost::io::basic_altstringbuf<Ch,Tr,Alloc>::overflow(int)' 1>
> with 1>        [ 1>            Ch=char, 1>
> Tr=std::char_traits, 1>            Alloc=std::allocator 1>
> ] 1>D:.conan\a9fe50\1\include\boost\format\format_class.hpp(173):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::io::basic_altstringbuf<Ch,Tr,Alloc>' being compiled 1>
> with 1>        [ 1>            Ch=char, 1>
> Tr=std::char_traits, 1>            Alloc=std::allocator 1>
> ]
> 1>D:\Documents\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(6):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::basic_format<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>'
> being compiled 1>Generating Code... 1>Done building project
> "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

## Environment

- OS: Win10-64bit
- VC++ 2019 16.10.0
- Configuration: x86
- SDK version: 10.0(latest installed version)
- Language: std:c++latest
- Boost: 1.73

I upgraded VC++ today from 16.9 to 16.10, then compilation was broken.
It only happens when I use `std:c++latest`, but works fine with 'std:c++17'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library lacks c++20 support (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate)

You can, for now, opt for c++17 compilation. Also, see whether they know about this issue, and if not report it to the developers.

#### Side Notes

- I take it the sample is reduced, but it seems to me the literal ought to be narrow, or the fmt ought to be `wformat`
- It appears that Boost 1.76 doesn't have this problem so, try upgrading boost

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a few months old now, but I just hit this same issue with boost 1.70 after upgrading VS 2019. All I did was remove the 2nd argument to the 'allocate' call on line 261 of alt_sstream_impl.hpp, since it's just a hint/optimization that was deprecated in c++ 17, and now gone in c++ 20. Fortunately, it's an inline method, so no linker issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can define _HAS_DEPRECATED_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS

It will reenable the removed "allocator stuff" in C++20 even when you compile with C++20 standard selected.